# wp_nav_menu() reutrns HTTPS?

Tags: menus, navigation

We have SSL for our domain. But there's only one page want to use SSL to appear on (`https://mydomain.com/secure-page/`). All others should be regular `http://` pages. So we've set **siturl** and **homeurl** both to `http://domain.com` and hardcoded link to secure-page.

On regular pages, all the navigation and others links appear non-ssl (`http://`) which is fine. But when on `https://domain.com/secure-page`, wp_nav_menu() returns `https://` URLs for all other pages of site which we don't want. Remember, siteurl and homeurl both are `http://`.

Why is it returning all https:// links for nav items?

**EDIT** It is client's requirement unfortunately. There's only one page in site with HTTPS.

Comment: Please explain **why** you want to do it that way. It could be that you are facing a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Then you need to fix the client, not WordPress.

Comment: I guess the easiest way to get this done is set all the menu items manually using `http://`. If you want to do it programmatically, you can try a `str_replace` of the object `$menu_item->url` and wrap it in a `is_ssl()` condition.